# Hudson doesn't use Maven-generated classpath?

Tags: java, hudson, maven, classpath

I'm trying to search the classpath in my project at runtime.  We use Maven for build management and Hudson for CI.  On my local box, of course, everything works great.  However, when Hudson is running unit tests, it can't find classes generated during the build -- Maven should be putting them in `./target/classes`, but when I log the classpath (`System.getProperty("java.class.path")`) from Hudson it only gives me a list with two maven-related JARs -- no directories at all, and certainly not the current project's compiler output directory.  Is this Hudson's fault?  Maven's?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

ETA: I *think* this might have been fixed by upgrading the Maven runtime used by Hudson.  The problem was that we were looking for plugin classes via reflection, similar to the ideas in [this post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t137693-find-all-implementing-classes-in-classpath.html) -- not that actual code, but it gives you the idea.  Anyway, it sounds like Hudson was using a classpath that only "bootstrapped" the actual test harness; for whatever reason it seems to be fixed now.  Long story short: if you have a similar problem, try upgrading your Maven.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Are tests failing with classpath errors?

Comment: Do you build your artifacts in your Hudson job with maven? If yes, why don't you use maven to run the unit tests right away too? Would work like a charm. everything is managed by maven and therefore no classpath issues. If, for whatever reason, you have two build steps, the first building the app and the second testing the app, be aware that modifications to the classpath are not accessible in following build steps. --- by the way, you can skip the unit tests on a dev machine with the parameter `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two fixes.  One, upgrade Maven.  Two, don't rely on classpath hackery to iterate over things your classloader can see, a la the "resource discovery" trick linked to in the description.